# GDB set breakpoints with absolute paths

Tags: gdb, clion, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug an application compiled with Ninja.

- I have my source code `/usr/local/...project-src/`
- I have my build output located at `/usr/local/...project-src/out/Debug/build`
- The compiled output includes debug information

  - `file out/Debug/build` includes:

    ```
    ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, with debug_info, not stripped
    ```
- I'm able to add breakpoints when using relative paths:

  ```
  cd /usr/local/...project-src
  gdb
  file out/Debug/build
  b x/y.cc:34
  # success
  Breakpoint 1 at <mem-loc>: file ../../x/y.cc, line 34.
  ```
- But when I use absolute paths, it fails

  ```
  cd /usr/local/...project-src
  gdb
  file out/Debug/build
  b /usr/local/...project-src/x/y.cc
  # failure
  No source file named /usr/local/...project/x/y.cc.
  ```
- `info source` prints `No current source file.`
- `dir` prints `Source directories searched: /usr/local/...project-src/out/Debug:$cdir:$cwd`

I've also tried:

- `b ../../x/y.cc`, I tried this since that's what the successful command outputs. Surprisingly, it didn't work which is really confusing me.
- running gdb from the root directory and other directories.
- doing `cd` to various directories after starting gdb
- messing around with `set substitute-path` and adding directories using `dir`

I'm hoping the solution is simple, since breakpoints, and variable values, and everything else works, just not with absolute paths.

Also worth noting, once I've successfully added a breakpoint to a file (using the relative path), the other paths also work (both the absolute path and the `../../x/y.cc` path).

Lastly, as to why I want absolute paths to work, I'm using CLion's remote-gdb configuration to connect to a gdbserver, and CLion is using absolute paths for whatever reason. Perhaps there is a way to configure CLion to just use the `x/y.cc` instead? I'm running the gdbserver with `gdbserver :2000 out/Debug/build` and configured CLion's target remote, symbol file, and sysroot. I've also tried setting the path mappings in CLion.

Edit, testing on a dummy HelloWorld project using `g++ -g` instead of `ninja` to build, I'm able to add breakpoints using absolute paths e.g. `b /usr/local/...untitled/main.cpp:4`. So it seems to be, for some reason, `gdb` supports full paths for the HelloWorld project built with g++, but not for the real project built with Ninja.

Comment: What version of GDB are you using?  I tried to reproduce this issue without any luck so far.

Comment: 8.3-gg4. When you were unable to reproduce, do you mean 1) You were able to add breakpoints using the absolute paths, or 2) CLIion was using the relative paths instead of absolute paths?

Comment: I was using absolute paths to set breakpoints in a binary that was compiled using relative paths, which seemed to match what you have.  I also setup a directory structure similar to what you have.  If you're running on Linux you could try running GDB under strace, the hunt the log to see what paths GDB actually tries to access when searching for your source file.  Your update talks about building with g++ vs ninja, but ninja is a build system, not a compiler, so it's still using a compiler (probably g++) to compile your code, your should find out what flags are actually used originally.

Comment: This is very helpful. I'll dig into my build configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tldr, resolved using `gdb --readnow`.

Per the comment suggestion I began digging into my build config. 2 things I noticed:

1) The issue disappeared if I built with less debug details. But then I wouldn't be able to inspect expressions & variables. So I thought the issue may somehow related to gdb not having enough memory or cache to load all the debug info. This sounds reasonable since the project source code contains 100,000's of files.

2) As I mentioned earlier, I could add breakpoints using absolute paths *after* I had added a breakpoint using a relative path to the same file.

I learnt of the `info`, `info set`, and `info sources` commands. Although the outputs were the same between the light-weight debug build and the full debug built (step 1), I noticed that the output of `info sources` changed in step 2. Before I had added the breakpoint using a relative path, `info sources would list all source files under 'Source files for which symbols will be read in on demand'. But after adding a relative breakpoint, a few of the files (I think the files on the current frame) would be added to the loaded source files.

So I went looking for a way to tell gdb to load all the source files and discovered the `gdb --readnow` flag (or `file <built-file> -readnow` with 1 dash `-`) and though it prints a bunch of warning messages, it seems to resolve my issue.

That being said, I never discovered how to configure CLion to use the `readnow` flag. The newest EAP (2019.3) release supposedly supports configuring `.gdbinit` files individual per project, though I haven't tried this. I also don't know if `readnow` can be configured in a `.gdbinit` file since it's not a setting. I kind of circumvented the entire configuring CLion issue when I figured how to correctly configure custom build targets and applications in CLion during this investigation.

Edit,

Yet another workaround. If I `cd` into `/usr/local/...project-src/out/Debug` which contains the build file (as opposed to `/usr/local/...project-src/`), then absolute paths work even without `readnow`.

Comment: This is a very nice finding, I think you should accept your own answer. Regarding the `readnow` option using a `.gdbinit` file, have you tried a `symbol-file -readnow` command? https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Files I guess this should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, that "works" in that it allows breakpoints with absolute paths. Though I should have mentioned I have multiple builds (symbol-files). Ideally, I'd want gdbinit to set some 'always-readnow' setting.